# Strange script or bug, while reviewing the answer

Tags: discussion, bug

Today while clearing the review list, I have seen so many answers edited by an anonymous user; and all edits were just removing spaces or adding html entity characters. Not just in 1, but in almost 8 answers have I seen these. So I came here to ask.

The message is like this

```
proposed 23 mins ago by an anonymous user
```

[image: See here]

As you can see in the above images, this user is only doing edits like this but I think he is not a user or what as I can't see any info about the user. So **is it bug or script?** Hope to get information/answer rather then downvotes :)

**UPDATED**

Now I got this line on the top of these types of edits :

```
Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully
```

Comment: It's probably some user using a script. Or just a new way to catch robo-reviewers :-)  Anybody who approves 3 or more of these edits should be given a 1-year review ban. (I'll leave some room for mis-clicking).

Comment: hahaahha hope this will be true :)

Comment: @S.L.Barth how many review you get to solve. I used to get 20 but today i got 40??

Comment: You normally get 20 edits, unless the queue exceeds a certain size (150 currently, but that number is subject to change). Then you get 40.

Comment: It is hard to puzzle out why an anonymous user would be using a script to suggest edits. The normal reason people do this is to gain lots of repz with minimal effort. That requires an account, though.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was thinking too. By using script for edits like this how will help them.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13608825 and all the similar edits, there's always a comment stating "555-555-0199@example.com" … googling that, I find it related to spam, but perhaps someone know more where exactly it originates?

Comment: @bwoebi: See [this thread on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111077/burpsuite-accidental-defacement-should-i-be-concerned). Apparently, there's a buggy (or, perhaps, broken-as-designed) "security testing tool" out there that tries to automatically fill in and submit forms, using that string as a default value for unrecognized form fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says right there: proposed by an anonymous user. People who aren't logged in can suggest edits, they'll enter the review queue.
Below is a screenshot taken in a Private Browsing session. The link doesn't appear on all questions, I don't know what the criteria are.

> [image: screenshot]

Review the edits as you normally would. If enough edits are rejected, the system will (hopefully) pick it up and take action.

Comment: At least some of these qualify as vandalism - making code snippets un-compilable. Reject as "spam or vandalism" where appropriate and the system might pick it up faster.

Comment: @stijn yes now system is saying _Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully_ this but user who aren't logged in how can do edits?

Comment: @Leothelion I've added a screenshot. The link doesn't appear on all questions, I don't know what the criteria are.

Comment: Yup was checking and i did. Thank you for answer but yet wait for more answer and if will not get then will go with your answer. Thank you